# Ramda group by with specific structure

Tags: ramda.js

I am trying to group some elements with Ramda and build a simple nested menu with it. I get such structure from backend:

```
const testArray = [
  {
    "id":6,
    "type":{
      "name":"Test1",
      "category":"Cat A"
    },
    "typeName":"Test1",
    "categoryName":"Cat A"
  },
  {
    "id":34,
    "type":{
      "name":"Test2",
      "category":"Cat A"
    },
    "typeName":"Test2",
    "categoryName":"Cat A"
  },
  {
    "id":662,
    "type":{
      "name":"Test6",
      "category":null
    },
    "typeName":"Test6",
    "categoryName":null
  },
  {
    "id":62,
    "type":{
      "name":"Test7",
      "category":"Cat A"
    },
    "typeName":"Test7",
    "categoryName":"Cat A"
  },
  {
    "id":1190,
    "type":{
      "name":"Test8",
      "category":null
    },
    "typeName":"Test8",
    "categoryName":null
  },
  {
    "id":"other",
    "type":{
      "name":"Others",
      "seen":true
    },
    "typeName":"Others"
  }
];
```

When I try to group it using:

```
const testRamda = R.groupBy(R.prop('categoryName'));
```

I get in result object with groups: Cat A, null, undefined because 'categoryName' contain name, null or nothing so it is undefined.

**This is what I am trying to achieve. Structure sorted alphabetically with "Others" always as last option.**

```
[
  {
    "name": "Cat A",
    "category": "Cat A",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Test1"
      },
      {
        "name": "Test2"
      },
      {
        "name": "Test7",
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Test6",
    "category": null
  },
  {
    "name": "Test8",
    "category": null
  },
  {
    "name": "Others"
  }
]
```

I will appreciate any help

Comment: Is there further recursive nesting of categories?

Comment: No. Only 1 level of 'nesting' is needed

Comment: Also, is your expected output correct?  I would guess that `Test 6` should go where `Test 7` is (it's missing altogether) and that `Test 7` would be nested under `Cat A`.  Is that right?  If not, what's the rule?

Comment: I didnt paste here whole JSON that is why Test 6 is missing. Rule is to group only this elements with category. Null and undefined category shouldn't be grouped.

Comment: This last JSON is what I would like to achieve if possible

Comment: It's still not clear to me why this: `{"id": 62, "type": {"name": "Test7", "category":"Cat A" }, "typeName": "Test7", "categoryName": "Cat A"}` does not sort into Category A.

Comment: You're confusing me, I'm afraid.  `{"id": 62, "type": {"name": "Test7", "category":"Cat A" }, "typeName": "Test7", ` **"categoryName": "Cat A"** `}`.  That input element seems to have category name `Cat A`.  I don't know why it's shouldn't sort there.  I can't figure out if this is just a mistaken input/output pair, or if there's much more going on in the grouping than I imagine.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Sorry. I was looking on this JSON and couldn't find mistake. Now it should be ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you're looking to do three separate things.  You want to group your elements by category.  You want to sort the categories so that those with no category comes at the very end, and those with `null` right before that.  And you want to transform your elements grouping the categories into single objects, and keeping the others separate.

This makes for a somewhat bizarre transformation.  But that's not too surprising, as both your input structure and your output structure are somewhat odd.

Here is one way that does *almost* what you ask:

```js
const compare = ([a], [b]) => 
  a == 'undefined' ? (b == 'undefined' ? '0' : 1) : b == 'undefined' ? -1
    : a == 'null' ? (b == 'null' ? 0 : 1) : b == 'null' ? -1
    : a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : 0
    
const makeCat = ([key, nodes]) => 
  key == 'null' || key == 'undefined'
    ? nodes .map (node => node .type)
    : [{name: key, category: key, children: nodes .map (({type: {name}}) => ({name}))}]

const transform = pipe (
  groupBy (prop ('categoryName')),
  toPairs, 
  sort (compare),
  chain (makeCat)
) 

// changing this to demonstrate proper grouping.
// const testArray = [{id: 6, type: {name: "Test1", category: "Cat A"}, typeName: "Test1", categoryName: "Cat A"}, {id: 34, type: {name: "Test2", category: "Cat A"}, typeName: "Test2", categoryName: "Cat A"}, {id: 662, type: {name: "Test6", category: null}, typeName: "Test6", categoryName: null}, {id: 62, type: {name: "Test7", category: "Cat A"}, typeName: "Test7", categoryName: "Cat A"}, {id: 1190, type: {name: "Test8", category: null}, typeName: "Test8", categoryName: null}, {id: "other", type: {name: "Others", seen: true}, typeName: "Others"}];
const testArray = [{id: 662, type: {name: "Test6", category: null}, typeName: "Test6", categoryName: null}, {id: 6, type: {name: "Test1", category: "Cat A"}, typeName: "Test1", categoryName: "Cat A"}, {id: 34, type: {name: "Test2", category: "Cat A"}, typeName: "Test2", categoryName: "Cat A"}, {id: 62, type: {name: "Test7", category: "Cat A"}, typeName: "Test7", categoryName: "Cat A"}, {id: 1190, type: {name: "Test8", category: null}, typeName: "Test8", categoryName: null}, {id: "other", type: {name: "Others", seen: true}, typeName: "Others"}];

console .log (
  transform (testArray)
)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
<script> const {pipe, groupBy, prop, toPairs, sort, chain} = R       </script>
```

- **`compare`** is used for sorting.  It places `undefined` categories at the end and `null` ones just before that, sorting the rest with a natural sort.  (There is a good argument to be made for making a more declarative version of this, but that's a separate question, I think.)
- **`makeCat`** takes a category name and a list of nodes from your original list, and creates and array of output nodes.  It handles the `null`/`undefined` cases separately from the true category ones.  When there is a true category, it creates an array containing a single-element with `name`, `category`, and `children` properties.  When the category is `null`/`undefined`, we simply extract the `type` property from each child, and return an array of them.  Here is what you might want to change if the slightly different output doesn't work for you.
- **`transform`** rolls all this together in a pipeline, first grouping by the elements by their `categoryName` property, then converting the resulting object into an array of `key`-`value` pairs, sorting the result with `compare`, and then calling `chain` (similar to `Array.prototype.flatMap` in this case) with `makeCat` on the resulting array.

The only behavior difference I note from your updated output request is that this includes the `seen` property in the last node.  This is because we just reuse the item's `type`.  If you want some different process, then you can simply replace `node => node .type` with something more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Scott's answer, we're going to make a little `Comparison` module. But before we get bogged down in implementation I want first want to establish an expectation for how it should work. We begin by writing two independent comparisons -

```js
const { empty, contramap, concat } =
  Comparison

const hasUndefinedCategory =
  contramap(empty, x => x.category === undefined)

const hasNullCategory =
  contramap(empty, x => x.category === null)
```

Next we show how comparisons can be combined -

```js
// primary sort: hasUndefinedCategory
// secondary sort: hasNullCategory
arr.sort(concat(hasUndefinedCategory, hasNullCategory))
```

`Comparison` should obey monoid functional laws so we can expect to combine any number of comparisons. N-sort works as follows -

```js
// primary sort: hasUndefinedCategory
// secondary sort: hasNullCategory
// tertiary sort: ...
arr.sort([ hasUndefinedCategory, hasNullCategory, ... ].reduce(concat, empty))
```

As for entries that have `children`, you can sort using `sortByName` -

```js
const sortByName =
  contramap(empty, x => x.name)

arr.forEach(({ children = [] }) => children.sort(sortByName))
```

Lastly, implement the `Comparison` module -

```js
const Comparison =
  { empty: (a, b) =>
      a < b ? -1
        : a > b ? 1
          : 0
  , contramap: (m, f) =>
      (a, b) => m(f(a), f(b))
  , concat: (m, n) =>
      (a, b) => Ordered.concat(m(a, b), n(a, b))
  }
```

Which relies on implementing the `Ordered` module -

```js
const Ordered =
  { empty: 0
  , concat: (a, b) =>
      a === 0 ? b : a
  }
```

---

Now that you're done you can go back and support things like `reverse` sorting -

```js
const Comparison =
  { // ...
  , reverse: (m) =>
      (a, b) => m(b, a)
  }

const { empty, contramap, concat, reverse } =
  Comparison

// N-sort
// first: hasUndefinedCategory in descending order
// second: hasNullCategory in ascending order (default)
// third: ...
const complexSort =
  [ reverse(hasUndefinedCategory)
  , hasNullCategory
  , ... 
  ].reduce(concat, empty)

arr.sort(complexSort)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const {ascend, apply, applySpec, complement, compose, concat, descend, groupBy, has, head, last, map, partition, pick, pipe, prop, sortWith, toPairs, useWith} = R;
const testArray = [{"id":1192,"type":{"name":"Z1","category":null},"typeName":"Z1","categoryName":null},{"id":1191,"type":{"name":"A1","category":null},"typeName":"A1","categoryName":null},{"id":6,"type":{"name":"Test1","category":"Cat A"},"typeName":"Test1","categoryName":"Cat A"},{"id":34,"type":{"name":"Test2","category":"Cat A"},"typeName":"Test2","categoryName":"Cat A"},{"id":662,"type":{"name":"Test6","category":null},"typeName":"Test6","categoryName":null},{"id":62,"type":{"name":"Test7","category":"Cat A"},"typeName":"Test7","categoryName":"Cat A"},{"id":1190,"type":{"name":"Test8","category":null},"typeName":"Test8","categoryName":null},{"id":"other","type":{"name":"Others","seen":true},"typeName":"Others"}];

const withCategoryTransformation = pipe(
  groupBy(prop("categoryName")),
  toPairs,
  map(applySpec({
    name:     head,
    category: head,
    children: pipe(last, map(compose(pick(["name"]), prop("type")))),
  })),
);

const withoutCategoryTransformation = 
  map(compose(pick(["name", "category"]), prop("type")));

const sortCriteria = [
  descend(has("category")),             // presence of "category" property
  ascend(complement(prop("category"))), // truthiness of "category" value
  ascend(prop("name")),                 // "name" value
];

const toMenuStructure = pipe(
  partition(prop("categoryName")),
  apply(useWith(concat, [withCategoryTransformation, withoutCategoryTransformation])),
  sortWith(sortCriteria),
);

console.log(toMenuStructure(testArray));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

1. I start of by splitting the collection into two groups. Those with a category name, and those without category name. (Based on truthiness of the "categoryName" value.)
2. Execute different operations for the collection with category name and those without category name, concatenating the resulting values.

   The following operations are performed on the group with category name:

   1. First group those with category name by their "categoryName" property.
   2. Convert the key/value-pairs back into an list.
   3. Transform each element, using the group key (`head`) as both "name" and "category" value. Then pick the "name" property of the "type" value for each item (`last`) and use that as "children".

      ```js
      // from
      [
        "Cat A",
        [
          {
            id: 34,
            type: {name: "Test1", category: "Cat A"},
            typeName: "Test1",
            categoryName: "Cat A"
          },
          /* ... */
        ]
      ]
      // to
      {name: "Cat A", category: "Cat A", children: [{name: "Test1"}, /* ... */]}
      ```

   The group without category only performs one operation:

   1. Pick the "name" and "category" property of the "type" value for each item. (Removing the "seen" property.)
3. We then sort all objects by the following: presence of the "category" property, truthiness/falseness of the category value, lastly the value of the "name" property.

---

I've chose to sort the "Others" to the end by checking for the presence of the "category" property. If you rather specifically filter out the name "Others" you can

```js
// replace
descend(has("category"))
// with
ascend(propEq("name", "Others"))
```

---

Depending on preference you could also go for alternative versions of `withCategoryTransformation` here are two alternatives for the last operation in the `pipe`:

```js
// Non point-free, but uses a more native JavaScript style.
map(([category, items]) => ({
  name:     category,
  category: category,
  children: items.map(compose(pick(["name"]), prop("type"))),
}))

// A point-free version that executes separate operations for the category
// and items, then merges the results together.
map(apply(useWith(mergeLeft, [
  applySpec({ name: identity, category: identity }),
  applySpec({ children: map(compose(pick(["name"]), prop("type"))) }),
])))
```